# Error Android Project

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I download all of the API and the last API for Marshmallow and when a create new Android project, it shows me error in Gradle.
Print screen below.
[image: n]

Comment: try using  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.0'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

junit is library for test
if you remove tthis line : testCompile : "junit......."  , (if you dont need test)
you can fix that bug